# req.params from app.delete is empty, using express, axios, in react

Tags: reactjs, express, sequelize.js, axios

How do I get req.params when using app.delete?

Here is part of my code in handleSubmit:

```
axios.delete("/api/emails/delete/", {params: {email: email}})
```

Here is my API route on the server:

```
app.delete("/api/emails/delete/", function(req, res) {
db.Email.destroy({
  where: {
    email: req.params.email
  }
})
.then(function(dbEmail) {
  console.log(req.params);
  res.json(dbEmail);
});
```

});

How do I get the req.params?

Thank

Answer (score 2):

**First way :**

I think you need to change :

```
axios.delete("/api/emails/delete/", { params : {email: email}})
```

to

```
axios.delete("/api/emails/delete/", { data : {email: email}})
```

Reason :

```
app.delete("/api/emails/delete/", function(req, res) { // <-- No params defined in roure
```

---

**Second Way :**

Keep :

```
axios.delete("/api/emails/delete/", { params : {email: email}})
```

AND change on express side :

```
app.delete("/api/emails/delete/:email", // <-- By this you can access req.params.email
```

Comment: unfortunately none of these options are working for me.  I liked the Second way best, so I tried that first and what it does is set `email` = `:email`

Comment: It should be working , you must be facing another issue after this , please check console from both side react and express ,Yes , @SierraKilo , if you are passing as params then it will append the value to your url , for more detail please read : https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: Without /:emails email=null with it literally is email =:email everything looks ok otherwise.